# Simplification of loop in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm still pretty new to Ruby, and am really enjoying the language. I came across this method in my code base and realized that it could be cleaned up:

```
def friend_all_followers(friends)
  client.followers.each do |follower|
    if not friends.include?(follower.screen_name)
      friend = Friend.new(:screen_name => follower.screen_name)
      client.friendship_create(friend.screen_name, true)
      friend.save
    end
  end
end
```

So I took the above and changed it to this:

```
def friend_all_followers(friends)
  followers = client.followers.reject { |f| friends.include?(f) }
  followers.each do |follower|
    friend = Friend.new(:screen_name => follower.screen_name)
    client.friendship_create(friend.screen_name, true)
    friend.save
  end
end
```

One less level of nesting, and cleaner than the first method. But I look at this method and can't help but think there's still more to be done. Any ideas?

As some background `Friend` is an `ActiveRecord` class, `client` is a wrapper around a Twitter API, `client.followers` returns an array of `follower` objects - the objects I believe are just hashes, but I'm not 100% certain at the moment - and `friends` is a string array of `screen_name`s.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can replace

```
friend = Friend.new(:screen_name => follower.screen_name)
client.friendship_create(friend.screen_name, true)
friend.save
```

With

```
friend = Friend.create(:screen_name => follower.screen_name)
client.friendship_create(friend.screen_name, true)
```

I'd also suggest wrapping creation of friend in separate class method:

```
class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
  def create_with_follower(follower = nil)
    return unless follower
    create :screen_name => follower.screen_name
  end  
end
```

Then code becomes like this:

```
friend = Friend.create_with_follower follower
client.friendship_create(friend.screen_name, true)
```

I'd probably hide the `friendship_create` method call somewhere too. Not sure what it does though. Is it separate API call?

**update**

Now whole code becomes like this:

```
def friend_all_followers(friends)
  followers = client.followers.reject { |f| friends.include?(f) }
  followers.each do |follower|
    friend = Friend.create_with_follower follower
    client.friendship_create(friend.screen_name, true)
  end
end
```

Now you can do some readable operation on array. Something like this:

```
def friend_all_followers(friends)
  (client.followers - friends).each do |follower|
    friend = Friend.create_with_follower follower
    client.friendship_create(friend.screen_name, true)
  end
end
```

Comment: Yup, friendship_create is used to create the friendship in twitter.

Comment: Is there any way to simplify the loop as well?

Comment: Please see my update. Not sure where to go from there .)

Comment: Getting rid of the call to save by using create only works if `friendship_create` doesn't do anything that needs to be saved.

Comment: @sepp2k - agreed, but since this is API call - there is no need for it to modify the passed in object.

Comment: @sepp2k you're right; luckily there is nothing done by `friendship_create`, so @Eimantas refactoring is correct. Also I didn't know you could use `-` between two arrays. That's awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Letting this percolate, I realized that I'm doing two things in `friend_all_followers`. The first is filtering new followers based on old followers (calling the variable `friends` obscures that, so I'll rename it), and the second is friending the new followers. By pulling the filtering into `new_followers`, I can rename `friend_all_followers` to a more explicit `friend_new_followers` like this:

```
def old_followers
  # ... get old followers
end

def new_followers
  client.followers.reject { |f| old_followers.include?(f) }
end

def friend_new_followers
  new_followers.each do |follower|
    friend = Friend.create(:screen_name => follower.screen_name)
    client.friendship_create(friend.screen_name, true)
  end
end
```